# How to add a list of elements to session in Play?

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm new to Play framework. How to add a list of elements to a session?

The compiler always complains about the code:

```
val cookies: List[(String, String)] = List[("a", "b), ("c", "d")]
Ok(views.html.hello(info)).withSession(request.session + cookies)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to copy existing session yourself:

```
val cookies: List[(String, String)] = List(("a", "b"), ("c", "d"))
Ok(views.html.hello(info)).addingToSession(cookies: _*)
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know the usage of `_*`